# Enabling multitouch on an acer 5742?

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, acer

I am trying to get multitouch to work on my touchpad. I am currently trying to run a script to get it to work. It is set to start on boot, saved as .run and has been made executable.

here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#enable multitouch

sleep 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8  1 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger  Pressure" 32 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger  Width" 32 8
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 8 0 0 0
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Jumpy Cursor Threshold" 32 110
synclient TapButton2=2
exit
```

the commands make multi touch work if I enter them in the terminal, but the script itself does not work. any suggestions?

Comment: Here is the same question by me --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/13389/command-works-partially-when-run-from-startup-applications

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar script that works on my Aspire:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 5
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 32 8
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1 1
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to run after you've logged in, not on boot. The xinput system is usually reset or prodded a lot with a sharp stick when you log in. You can either run your script in your start up items (System > Preferences > Startup Items) or you can make yourself a nice udev rule which will configure the device correctly and you can pass the udev rule on to others:

See this for information about writing input udev rules:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Input%20Configuration%20with%20udev%20%28Ubuntu%2010.04%29

Answer (score 0):

I came across this fix which works just fine for me and recognizes two fingers (scroll and right click).
Just download this package -->

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/308191/+attachment/1735234/+files/synaptics-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb

As per comments on the bug report, this package has worked for most of the multitouch touchpads including Acer. Three finger touch didn't work for me.

read comment #115 and #116 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/308191/+index?comments=all

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Enabling%20True%20Multitouch  worked great and easy for me