# Command works partially when run from startup applications

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I have this script (or rather a set of commands which has permission to execute) to enable **two finger scrolling** and **two finger tap = right click**
The script is located in **/home/gaurav/Multigesture/multigesture**.

When I run the following command in terminal, **two finger scrolling** and **two finger tap = right click** start working. I have to run this command each time I boot my laptop.

> "/home/gaurav/Multigesture/multigesture"

So I put this command in the **startup applications** so that I dont have to run the command each time I boot but when I reboot **two finger scrolling** is not working, only **two finger tap = right click** works.

What could be the problem, If the command works fine from the terminal then how come it is working partially when i put it into startup applications.

Here is the content of the script

> xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics
>   TouchPad" "Two-Finger Scrolling" 8 1
>   xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics
>   TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger
>   Scrolling" 8 1 1 xinput set-int-prop
>   "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
>   "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 32 10
>   xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics
>   TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width"
>   32 8

PS. the file which has all the commands (script's) name is **multitouch**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this fix which works just fine for me and recognizes two fingers (scroll and right click). Just download this package -->

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/308191/+attachment/1735234/+files/synaptics-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb

As per comments on the bug report, this package has worked for most of the multitouch touchpads including Acer. Three finger touch didn't work for me.

read comment #115 and #116 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/308191/+index?comments=all

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but

Copy the script to `/etc/init.d/`

Like

> sudo cp multitouch /etc/init.d/multitouch

And then update the script to work in runlevel 2345

> sudo update-rc.d multitouch defaults

and then enable this command using `rcconf`

> sudo rcconf

Select the multitouch options using space bar and hit OK

reboot the system

You might need to install the package `rcconf`

> sudo apt-get install rcconf

Hope this works

---

This tutorial gives a better insight on how update-rc works.
http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d

Google for runlevels if you want to gain more knowledge.

Comment: :( when I put it into startup apps, command partially works but from the above mentioned method the script doesn't seem to run at all, whereas when I do sudo "/etc/init.d/multigesture" everything works fine.

Comment: I added the answer. Check the `sudo update-rc.d multitouch defaults` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a script load at boot up by making it an init scripts. Here is a how-to: [Ubuntu bootup howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)

Comment: I think this is the same process that @Manish has suggested which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works either but

add this line to /etc/rc.local (before "exit 0"):

/home/gaurav/Multigesture/multigesture

Comment: looks like /etc/rc.local doesn't run on the startup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an howto for setting up scripts for touchpad: [ubuntu community documentation EEE PC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/1001P). The section on `multi-touch` alnswers your question on runnning scripts at boot.

Comment: That is the same thing I am doing mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a simple upstart startup script. Create a file in /etc/init with the .conf extension. In the file put:

`start on started tty1`

exec /home/gaurav/Multigesture/multigesture

Answer (score 0):

Slowing the startup script maybe helps...

I've had a problem with conky because the xserver was not completely loaded when startup application started conky.

I resolved with:

`#!/bin/bash`

`sleep 10 && conky;`

you sould just change conky with your script name (and path) :)